# MapsForge dynamically added overlay items do not redraw

Tags: android, android-mapview, openstreetmap

I wanted to add some Overlay items to MapsForge at runtime; I can successfully add them, but they appear only after i move or zoom the map. As it should actually be, since with every moving or zooming, MapsForge manage to redraw the tiles and the overlaying items through the `invalidate()` function. Anyway, [as it is stated here](http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/issues/detail?id=69), this is an issue already fixed since MapsForge release 0.2.0: MapView Class should automatically be able to redraw new items whenever they're added.

I am using MapsForge 0.3.1. Either I am doing something wrong, or this issue reappeared in current release. Here is my code; I reused some code from [the official MapsForge Sample activities](http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/source/browse/#git%2FApplications%2FAndroid%2FSamples%2Fsrc%2Forg%2Fmapsforge%2Fapplications%2Fandroid%2Fsamples):

```
public class MyMapView extends MapView{

    //I brought some variables outside the Sample's function in order to add new items dynamically to the lists
    ListOverlay mListOverlay;
    List<OverlayItem> mOverlayItems;
    Polyline mPolyline;
    Circle mLastPosition;

    //Basically here I do the same actions shown in the MapsForge samples. These items appear at once, with the onCreate() functions of the Activity
    public void addInitialOverlays(){
        Circle circle = createCircle(CENTRAL_STATION);
        Polygon polygon = createPolygon(Arrays.asList(VICTORY_COLUMN, CENTRAL_STATION, BRANDENBURG_GATE));
        mPolyline = createPolyline(Arrays.asList(BRANDENBURG_GATE, VICTORY_COLUMN));
        Marker marker1 = createMarker(R.drawable.marker_red, VICTORY_COLUMN);
        Marker marker2 = createMarker(R.drawable.marker_green, BRANDENBURG_GATE);

        mLastPosition = createCircle(VICTORY_COLUMN);

        mOverlayItems.add(circle);
        mOverlayItems.add(polygon);
        mOverlayItems.add(mPolyline);
        mOverlayItems.add(marker1);
        mOverlayItems.add(marker2);
        mOverlayItems.add(mLastPosition);
        getOverlays().add(mListOverlay);
    }

    //Here is the relevant part. This is called periodically from the main Activity
    public void addPointToRoute(double latitude, double longitude) {

        GeoPoint newPoint = new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude);
        //Tried both removing the list from the overlays and re-adding it, and leaving it where it is; same result
        //getOverlays().remove(mListOverlay);
        mOverlayItems.remove(mPolyline);
        List<GeoPoint> oldPolyline = mPolyline.getPolygonalChain().getGeoPoints();
        oldPolyline.add(newPoint);
        mPolyline = createPolyline(oldPolyline);
        mOverlayItems.add(mPolyline);
        mLastPosition.setGeoPoint(newPoint);
        //getOverlays().add(mListOverlay);

        invalidateOnUiThread();//This MapView function calls either invalidate() or postInvalidate(), depending on the situation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding the overlaycontroller after adding the overlay items

> In fact i found out that you can just use another function instead.

example:

```
mapView.getOverlays().add(listOverlay);
//redraw once overlay items have been added/removed
mapView.getOverlayController().redrawOverlays(); //method 1
/**OR**/
mapView.redraw(); //method 2
```

hope this helps!